# How does this word replacement function work?

Tags: python, regex, function, python-3.x

```
import re
def multiwordReplace(text, wordDic):
    rc = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, wordDic))))
    def translate(match):
        return wordDic[match.group(0)]
    return rc.sub(translate, text)
```

This code was copied from another source, but I am unsure on how it replaces the words in a passage of text and don't understand why the 're' function is used here

Comment: You should read about the [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Comment: What should we do with such questions? It is not a question like [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean), but similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piece by piece...

```
 # Our dictionary
 wordDic = {'hello': 'foo', 'hi': 'bar', 'hey': 'baz'}

 # Escape every key in dictionary with regular expressions' escape character. 
 # Escaping is requred so that possible special characters in 
 # dictionary words won't mess up the regex
 map(re.escape, wordDic)

 # join all escaped key elements with pipe | to make a string 'hello|hi|hey'
'|'.join(map(re.escape, wordDic))

 # Make a regular expressions instance with given string.
 # the pipe in the string will be interpreted as "OR", 
 # so our regex will now try to find "hello" or "hi" or "hey"
 rc = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, wordDic)))
```

So **rc** now matches with words there are in the dictionary and **rc.sub** replaces those words in given string.The translate funtion just returns corresponding value for the key when regex returns a match.

Answer (score 1):

1. `re.compile()` - Compiles the expression string to regex object. The string consists of the concatenated keys of the `worDic` with a separator `|`. Given a `wordDic` `{'hello':'hi', 'goodbye': 'bye'}` the string would be 'hello|hi' which could be tranlated to "hello *or* hi"
2. `def translate(match):` - defines a callback function which will process every match
3. `rc.sub(translate, text)` - Performes the string replacement. If regex matches the text, the matches (actually keys of `wordDic`) are looked up in the wordDic via the callback and the translation is returned.

Example:

```
wordDic = {'hello':'hi', 'goodbye': 'bye'}
text = 'hello my friend, I just wanted to say goodbye'
translated = multiwordReplace(text, wordDic)
print(translated)
```

Output is:

```
hi my friend, I just wanted to say bye
```

**EDIT**

The main advantage of using `re.compile()` though is the performance gain if the regex is used multiple times. As the regex is compiled on every function call, there is no gain. If `wordDic` is used multiple times, you generate a `multiwordReplace` function for the `wordDic` and the compiling is done just once:

```
import re
def generateMwR(wordDic):
    rc = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, wordDic)))
    def f(text):
        def translate(match):
            print(match.group(0))
            return wordDic[match.group(0)]
        return rc.sub(translate, text)
    return f
```

Usage would be like this:

```
wordDic = {'hello': 'hi', 'goodbye': 'bye'}
text = 'hello my friend, I just wanted to say goodbye'
f = generateMwR(wordDic)
translated = f(text)
```